# BitmapFont in Skin doesn't draw labels correctly

Tags: label, libgdx, skin, bitmap-fonts

I made a bitmap font using Hiero, called `default.fnt` and `default.png`. I can use these as a BitmapFont in LibGDX, and draw text with the font without problems, using `font.draw()`. But I can't use this font as the default font in a Skin. I've used the uiskin.json file from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json)(along with the rest of the skin, but I deleted the Droid Sans files before making my own font), because I have no idea how to make one of my own. From what I've read on the Internet, the .json file is correctly set up: it has the line `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } }`, which should make the `default.fnt` the default font for widgets that use the skin. Still, when I run the program, I see this:

[image: Label in window that should show text shows only part of an A, buttons that should have labels empty]

There should be a label above the buttons, and the buttons should have text.

If I do this: `startGameButton.getStyle().font = font;`, where `startGameButton` is one of the buttons, and `font` is the `BitmapFont` created like this: `font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin/default.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("uiskin/default.png"), false);`, the buttons shows the text properly. I don't want to do this since it feels too much like a hack.

I'm following [this](http://steigert.blogspot.com/) tutorial, but I've had to look some things up in later revisions of his code, because LibGDX has changed since it was written.

[MenuScreen.java](http://pastebin.com/NZH3pkGw)(the screen where there are problems)

[AbstractScreen.java](http://pastebin.com/G5riB9PV)

Also please tell me if there's a better way to make the menu UI, or if you need other files. The `uiskin.json` is linked above.

Thank you.

Comment: Everything you are doing looks correct. I have only added fonts before and not replaced the default, but it should work fine. Do you mind posting information about your libGDX version and a copy of your font file/image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The Droid Sans bitmap image existed in two places, it was part of `uiskin.png` too. I don't know how, but it probably read the font's letters from that file instead of `default.png`. So in the end I just renamed the font's `.fnt` and `.png`(and the `file` parameter in the `.fnt`) and did a search-replace inside the skin's `.json`, and it all works fine now. I don't know exactly what caused it, but maybe `default-font` is a reserved word or something.

Anyway, it works now. Thanks to Jyro117 for making me think maybe I shouldn't replace the default but add my own font.